# How to convert $date (used to ISODate) to NSDate in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mongodb, nsdate

Now I'm working with objective-c and mongodb.

I use AFNetworking Framework to send the http request from my application to server (bottlepy server) to connect mongodb database.

In mongodb the information I need look like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532083b7a67a6a14589c876e"),
    "myDate" : ISODate("2014-02-08T00:00:00Z")
}
```

but when I use AFNetworking to get this. It is auto convert to

```
{
    "_id" = {
        "$oid" = 532083b7a67a6a14589c876e;
    };
    myDate = {
        "$date" = 1391817600000;
    };
}
```

So How to covert $date to NSDate??? ?

Really Thank you.

Comment: Hint - it's the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

Comment: I heard rumors that StackExchange implemented a surveillance script: if no NSDate conversion question is asked within 30 min, an alarm goes off and the server admins investigate, if stackoverflow.com maybe is unreachable for some or all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1391817600000/1000];
```

generates:

```
2014-02-08 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: You should be doing floating point division, not integer division (though if the number of milliseconds is always 0, it won't make a difference).